# Merge mp3 with jpg and add moving volume as background

Tags: mp4, photos

I'm trying to put an image with a song and save it as a mp4.

But I need some app makes me able to add simple moving edits to the background like Volumes moving

Something like this :
[image: example]

I wish you can help me

This is a video example : 
[this video](https://youtu.be/ei_x0w9wc4s)